# How to Output the variables from resulting SAS Data Set into fixed length flat file

Tags: sas

How to Output the variables from resulting SAS Data Set into fixed length flat file, looking like:

12/09/2010 Houston TX 77077

10/16/2009 Houston TX 77040

9/18/2009 Katy TX 77450

Comment: Show what you tried. How did it not meet your needs?  Hint: Use the PUT statement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc print data=yourstuff;
run;

/* or */

libname here './'; run;

data _null_;
   file here.flat;
   set yourstuff;
```